# Does the angular-translate library require translation files to be packaged with your app?

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I am new to angular and to the angular-translate library.

I am wondering if the files need to be packaged with your app/stored client side.

e.g.

```
locale/
---- en.json
```

Can the library deal with remote files on a server? If so, how?

Comment: yes it can deal with remote files. Have a look at [asynchronous-loading](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

Comment: Does it have to be done in the app.js file during configuration? Or can you do it at a later time after the user has logged into your app? How would I do it after a login page?

Comment: maybe you can have it in `routeChangeStart` of your post-login or something similar in your current router.. which can be placed in app.js

Comment: Thanks @tanmay! Do you have an example of $routeChangeStart?

Comment: maybe something like [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/RjNJbC/preview)